# Free/fairly basic web browsers for Android TV

Tags: web-browser, android-tv, smart-tv

I'm trying to get a TV set up for my dad - it's running Android TV 11 - and I'm trying to essentially run something like Chrome without sideloading it, for accessing websites with media that don't have an 'official' Google TV app.

It runs 1080p and is a pretty generic Google TV.

In a perfect world, I'd just load Chrome or Firefox via the Google app store and get on with my life. I need HTML5 video playback, or essentially something on par with a phone or desktop browser.

[Odin browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hisense.odinbrowser) comes *close* to what I need other than the window being slightly larger than my screen and I need to scroll to see all of it. It's also 'stuck' at 100% size so I can't try resizing it to fit.

The TV comes with [Puffin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmosa.puffinTV) installed - but it is subscription based and paying for a browser seems odd.

What, practically, would be my options for a free web browser for a TV?

Answer (score 0):

**TV Bro**

It is free and open-source. In my opinion, it is the best browser to use with a remote control.

Links:

- [Website](https://tvbro.phlox.dev/)
- [Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phlox.tvwebbrowser)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/truefedex/tv-bro)